# dynamically show/hide content based on window width

Tags: html, css, dhtml

I am building a website and I need it to behave so that if the window is fullscreen (or any size where width > X px) - it should show the sidebar. If the user resizes the window's width below a certain amount, the sidebar should disappear (display:none).

A prime example to look at is google's news page (news.google.com) - there is a right sidebar which is only visible when the width of the page is above a certain threshold.

I'm usually pretty good in searching google/stack exchange and finding the answer I need, but in this case, maybe it's because of the use of the word 'dynamic' but I can't think of any other way to phrase it, i'm getting a lot of hits which are not what I need.

If I were to think of a solution on my own, I would perhaps add a javascript listener which constantly monitors the x value of the 'viewable area' and have a function constantly running that would do something like, if viewable area X value is lower than my threshold, change the style of my sidbar div to display:none. I think that would work, but I don't know if it's the best way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

What about [max-width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453836.aspx) Media Queries?

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 768px ) {
 /* When the viewport is 768px or less, 
    hide #sidebar */
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/6Pvyt/show/

For IE6-8, https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 1):

I believe CSS Media Queries is the best solution as answered already by Jonathan Sampson,

but as youve hinted at it in your question about using a javascript listener I thought I best explain a better (IMO) JS solution using jQuery's on event.

e.g.

```
jQuery(window).on({
    "resize": function(){
        if(jQuery(window).width() > 750) {
             //code to show sidebar
            jQuery(#sidebar).removeclass("hidden");
        } else {
            //code to hide sidebar e.g.
            jQuery(#sidebar).addclass("hidden");
        }
}
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is CSS Media queries.  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

I use Twitter's [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework which includes a whole slew of responsive screen functionality.